# How to pass an action via url in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I have a form in my view, and I want to call my action and update my table when I submit my form,**but when i submitted the form my table doesn't updated and the form redirect me to /users/{id}**  so this is my action:

```
public function userToadmin($id)
{
$service = User::find($id);
$service->role      = '0';
$service->save();

// redirect
Session::flash('message', 'Successfully granted the user!');
return Redirect::to('users');
```

This is my form :

```
{{ Form::open(array('title'=>'Add Admin Role','url' => 'userToadmin', 'class' => 'pull-left')) }}
{{ Form::hidden('_method', 'EDIT') }}
{{ Form::submit('', array('class' => 'update-event', 'data-title'=>'Delete User', 'data-content' => 'Are you sure you want to grant this user to admin ?', 'onClick'=>'return false;',)) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And this is my route :

```
Route::post('userToadmin', array('uses' => 'UserController@userToadmin'));
```

Comment: what is wrong happened with you,when you submit your form ?

Comment: Where do you get $id?

Comment: userToadmin function expects one route parameter ($id) and you don't have any in your route. Don't you have any errors?

Comment: Erm, I think the _method = 'EDIT' will severely mess up your system. That should be POST, DELETE, etc. Also, I'm not sure you pass 'url' to the `Form::open()` helper. Where did you get all this code from? Kinda looks like you made it up in the hopes it'd work, but maybe I just have a lack of knowledge about all of this.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with some of the bad practices you're using in your Form code.

```
{{ Form::open(array('title'=>'Add Admin Role','url' => 'userToadmin', 'class' => 'pull-left')) }}
```

This should use a route name instead of a 'url'. You can check out how to do this [in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form), but here's an example of how your route should look like, and the relative input in your Form:

```
//you should be using proper camel casing too...userToadmin should be userToAdmin
Route::post('userToAdmin', array('as' => 'user.makeAdmin', 'use' => 'UserController@userToAdmin'));

{{ Form::open(array('title'=>'Add Admin Role','route' => 'user.makeAdmin', 'class' => 'pull-left', 'method' => 'put')) }}
```

Notice how I also specified the HTTP method to use when processing the form. By default, Laravel assumes PUT, but you can specify it if you'd like. No need to create a hidden form field for your method.

Also,how you're using [Session with a redirect isn't the most efficient method](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects). You should do something like:

```
//in place of your redirect...assuming you have a route called 'users'
return Redirect::route('users')->with('message','Successfully granted the user!');
```

To specifically tackle the issue with not updating your user...that code SHOULD be saving your User model just fine. You may want to try a var_dump($service) before and after you alter $service->role to make sure you're getting what you're expecting.

There may be an issue somewhere else in your code that's not passing the correct user id.